# Apache drill 1.7 build failure

Tags: maven, build, build-process, apache-drill

Trying to build apache drill from git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/drill.git

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Drill Root POM .............................. SUCCESS [ 13.700 s]
[INFO] tools/Parent Pom ................................... SUCCESS [  2.708 s]
[INFO] tools/freemarker codegen tooling ................... SUCCESS [  7.458   s]
[INFO] Drill Protocol ..................................... SUCCESS [ 16.764 s]
[INFO] Common (Logical Plan, Base expressions) ............ SUCCESS [ 13.602 s]
[INFO] Logical Plan, Base expressions ..................... SUCCESS [ 15.324 s]
[INFO] exec/Parent Pom .................................... SUCCESS [  5.805 s]
[INFO] exec/memory/Parent Pom ............................. SUCCESS [  1.478 s]
[INFO] exec/memory/base ................................... SUCCESS [ 10.578 s]
[INFO] exec/rpc ........................................... SUCCESS [  4.130 s]
[INFO] exec/Vectors ....................................... SUCCESS [01:24 min]
[INFO] contrib/Parent Pom ................................. SUCCESS [  1.237 s]
[INFO] contrib/data/Parent Pom ............................ SUCCESS [  1.031 s]
[INFO] contrib/data/tpch-sample-data ...................... SUCCESS [  4.037 s]
[INFO] exec/Java Execution Engine ......................... FAILURE [ 49.806 s]
[INFO] exec/JDBC Driver using dependencies ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] JDBC JAR with all dependencies ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] contrib/kudu-storage-plugin ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] contrib/mongo-storage-plugin ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] contrib/hbase-storage-plugin ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] contrib/jdbc-storage-plugin ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] contrib/hive-storage-plugin/Parent Pom ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] contrib/hive-storage-plugin/hive-exec-shaded ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] contrib/hive-storage-plugin/core ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] contrib/drill-gis-plugin ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Packaging and Distribution Assembly ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] contrib/sqlline .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- ---
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:53 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-29T16:34:33+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 102M/795M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
2:compile (default-compile) on project drill-java-exec: Compilation failure -> [
Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute    goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-    compile) on project drill-java-exec: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException:    Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(Abstrac
tCompilerMojo.java:913)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.ja
va:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:207)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please   read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]     http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the   command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :drill-java-exec
```

My environment:
Maven version 3.3.9
Java version 1.7.0_45

Anyone who has faced such issues please give suggestions, solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Even I got an issue few days back it saying Some unit tests are failing. 
So i used `mvn install -DskipTests` to continue.

follow this [link](https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/INSTALL.md), i used `git clone https://github.com/apache/drill.git` repo.